# jQuery UI dialog not showing, backbone, Django

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, modal-dialog, requirejs

I have a problem. In my django templates I have django, require, jQuery UI.

The thing is that a template loading at the bottom should be a dialog, some sort of modal, with the jQuery UI. But doesn't show as a modal but as part of the first content.

This is the pos_send_to_admin.html which appears at the end of the website, instead of being a modal.

```
<code>
{% extends "pos/pos_homepage.html" %}
{% block windows %}
<form id="send_admin" title="Balance" class="send_admin"`enter code here`
    action="{% url 'pos-send-balance' %}"  method="post"
    onsubmit="return confirm('Do you really want to submit the report?');">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table class="table unselectable">
        <thead><tr>
            <td colspan=2>Description</td>
            <td>Peruvian soles (S/.)</td>
            <td>American Dollars(US$)</td>
        </tr></thead>
        <tbody><tr>
            <td colspan=2>Fondo de caja de apertura</td>
            <td id="last_soles">{{ balance_status.initial_soles }}</td>
            <td id="last_dollars">{{ balance_status.initial_dollars }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=2>Ingresos totales brutos</td>
            <td id="total_soles">{{ balance_status.inflow_soles }}</td>
            <td id="total_dollars">{{ balance_status.inflow_dollars }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=2>Ajustes anteriores</td>
            <td id="adjust_soles">{{ balance_status.adjust_soles }}</td>
            <td id="adjust_dollars">{{ balance_status.adjust_dollars }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Dinero en caja teórico</td>
            <td id="teoric_soles"></td>
            <td id="teoric_dollars"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Dinero en caja real</td>
            <td id="soles_adjust">{{pos_adjust_form.adjust_soles}}</td>
            <td id="dollars_adjust">{{pos_adjust_form.adjust_dollars}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Ajuste</td>
            <td id="soles_inflows"></td>
            <td id="dollars_inflows"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=2>Fondo de caja para sgte. turno</td>
            <td id="send_in_soles">{{pos_send_form.send_in_soles}}</td>
            <td id="send_in_dollars">{{pos_send_form.send_in_dollars}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="head">
            <td colspan=2>Deposito recepcion</td>
            <td id="deposit_soles">0</td>
            <td id="deposit_dollars">0</td>
        </tr></tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="buttons dcenter button-bar align-center">
        <input class="btn btn-large btn-info" type="submit" value="Ok and send">
        <a class="btn color_button_white btn-large btn-danger" href="{% url 'home' %}" >Cancel</a>
    </div>
</form>
{% endblock windows %}
{% block css %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/rep_balance_status.css">
{% endblock css %}

{% block script %}
     {{ block.super }}
    <script data-main="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/pos/main_send_to_admin.js" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}libs/require.js"></script>
    <script data-main="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/pos/other/send_to_admin.js" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}libs/require.js"></script>
{% endblock script %}
</code>
```

This is the send_to_admin.js file which is not called, so there is no modal

```
<code>define([
    'jquery',
    'backbone',
    'jquery.ui',
    'jquery.keyboard'
    ],
    function($){
        var calculate = function(){
            var last_soles =  parseFloat($('#last_soles').html());
            var last_dollars =  parseFloat($('#last_dollars').html());
            var total_soles =  parseFloat($('#total_soles').html());
            var total_dollars =  parseFloat($('#total_dollars').html());
            var adjust_soles = parseFloat($('#adjust_soles').html());
            var adjust_dollars = parseFloat($('#adjust_dollars').html());
            var teoric_soles = last_soles + total_soles + adjust_soles;
            var teoric_dollars = last_dollars + total_dollars + adjust_dollars;
            $('#teoric_soles').html(teoric_soles);
            $('#teoric_dollars').html(teoric_dollars);
            //ajuste
            var soles_adjust = parseFloat($('#id_adjust_soles').val());
            var dollars_adjust = parseFloat($('#id_adjust_dollars').val());
            var soles_inflows = (teoric_soles - soles_adjust)*-1;
            var dollars_inflows = (teoric_dollars - dollars_adjust)*-1;
            $('#soles_inflows').html(soles_inflows);
            $('#dollars_inflows').html(dollars_inflows);
            //total
            var send_in_soles = parseFloat($('#send_in_soles input').val());
            var send_in_dollars = parseFloat($('#send_in_dollars input').val());
            var deposit_soles = soles_adjust - send_in_soles;
            var deposit_dollars = dollars_adjust - send_in_dollars;
            $('#deposit_soles').html(deposit_soles);
            $('#deposit_dollars').html(deposit_dollars);
        };
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $( "form#send_admin" ).dialog({
                autoOpen: true,
                show: "blind",
                hide: "blind",
                modal: false,
                width: 600,
                resizable: false,
                closeOnEscape: true
            });
            //Kids: Dont' try this at home
            $(".type_input input").addClass("input-small numberKeyboard");
            $( ".numberKeyboard" ).keyboard({layout: 'custom',
                  customLayout: {
                   'default' : [
                    '0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9',
                    '{bksp} {accept} {cancel} '
                   ]
                  },
                  accepted: function(){
                      calculate();
                  }
            });
            $("form#send_admin input:text").change(function(){
                calculate();
            });
            calculate();
            $('#soles_adjust input').val(parseFloat($('#teoric_soles').html()));
            $('#dollars_adjust input').val(parseFloat($('#teoric_dollars').html()));
            calculate();
        });
    }
);
</code>
```

And this is the main_send_to_admin.js

```
<code>
var Aplication = {};
require.config({
    'paths': {
        jquery: '../../libs/jquery.min',
        underscore: '../../libs/underscore',
        backbone: '../../libs/backbone/backbone',
        ajaxSend: '../tools/ajaxSend',
        bootstrap: '../../libs/bootstrap3/js/bootstrap.min',
        'jquery.ui': '../../js/jquery-ui',
        'jquery.keyboard': '../tools/jquery.keyboard'
    },
    'shim': {
        bootstrap: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        backbone: {
            deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        underscore: {
            exports: '_'
        },
        ajaxSend: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'jquery.keyboard': {
            deps: ['jquery', 'jquery.ui']
        }
    }
});
require([
    //carga el modulo de app
    'app','ajaxSend','bootstrap','other/send_to_admin'
], function(App) {
    // The "app" dependency is passed in as "App"
    // Again, the other dependencies passed in are not "AMD" therefore don't
    // pass a parameter to this function
    App.initialize();
});
</code>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was silly, i fixed it changing the load order of some of the files.